# How to change PhpStorm rearrange code alphabetic

Tags: phpstorm

I want to change my PhpStorm code re-arrangement. I want to change all functions to alphabetic and then group by private, public or protected function.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: So .. what settings do you have now there?

Comment: I have only the basic settings cause i couldnt get it done

Comment: So .. SHOW what you have got there. I personally do not use it (right now) .. but have tried it about 6-9 months ago and it worked OK for my needs.

Comment: Also -- provide some sample class/file on which I can test the settings -- so that we are both on the same page (what if different code gets processed differently?)

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this is by going to *Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP*
In the window `Matching rules` select the/a method rule and double click it.
Set order to `order by name` and select one modifier(Public, Protected or Private). Add new rules for the other modifiers and rearange them in the order you want the modifiers to appear in.

When you next rearrage the code it be sorted correctly.

Example (using fields, but should behave the same):

```
/* Before */
public $a;
private $z;
public $d;
public $c;
private $j;
public $e;
protected $b;
protected $t;

/* After */
public    $a;
public    $c;
public    $d;
public    $e;
protected $b;
protected $t;
private   $j;
private   $z;
```

(Note: This was done with Windows 10 on PHPStorm 2017.1. I do not know the exact way of performing this action on Mac or Linux machines)